# How to update the text of a tag in XML using Elementree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Using elementree, the easiest way to read the text of a tag is to do the following:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
sKeyMap = ET.parse("KeyMaps/KeyMap_Checklist.xml")
host = sKeyMap.findtext("/BrowserInformation/BrowserSetup/host")
```

Now I want to update the text in the same file, hopefully without having to re-write it with something easy like:

```
host = "4444"
sKeyMap.replacetext("/BrowserInformation/BrowserSetup/host")
```

Any ideas?

Thx in advance
Christopher

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the value of the `<host>` element in your text file you should get a handle to the element using `find()` rather than just reading the text using `findtext()`. Once you have the element you can easily get the text out using `element.text`. Since you have the element you can easily reset its value as shown below:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
sKeyMap = ET.parse("KeyMaps/KeyMap_Checklist.xml")
host_element = sKeyMap.find("/BrowserInformation/BrowserSetup/host")
host = host_element.text
print host
# Now reset the the text of the <host> element
host = "4444"
host_element.text = host
```

Answer (score 1):

building on Tendayi's example maybe try something like:

```
newXmlContent = ET.tostring(sKeyMap)
fileObject = open("KeyMaps/newKeyMap_Checklist.xml","w") #note I used a different filename for testing!
fileObject.write(newXmlContent)
fileObject.close()
```